# HTML5 Mobile List in CSS

Tags: css, html, list, mobile

I'd like to be able build an HTML5 mobile app with the native feel.

However, I haven't found a good solution for lists, does anyone have any suggestions for creating a native feeling lists for html5 mobile app? I'd like to also leverage CSS animations and NOT use Jquery (or Jquery mobile).

Comment: what you mean "native feeling lists"?

Comment: like a native android or ios list box that scrolls smoothly and animates when there is a selection...

Answer (score 0):

May be iScroll will be good for you?
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4